# How to use ternary for this if statement?

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

```
if (msg.Body.Contains("logging"))
{
    enableLogs = !enableLogs;
    sendMsg(enableLogs == true ? "Logging enabled." : "Logging disabled.");
}
else if (msg.Body.Contains("afk"))
{

}
```

How would I go about turning this into a ternary if statement? It's not necessary if it won't work out nice, trying to make my program cleaner.

Comment: Maybe this is a lack of creativity on my part, but I don't see the ternary operator making that any easier to read.

Comment: Remove the `== true` part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ternary statements are **strictly for assignments**, not for `else-if` or multi-decision logic. It would only work if **both logic paths returned an instance of a type**. :)

```
var result = booleanValue ? logicPathForTrue : logicPathForFalse;
```

A "good" (academic) use of ternary:

```
// Assign something to result. If something is null, assign new Something to result
Something result = something == null ? new Something() : something;
```

**Ternary operations require variable assignment. This compiles:**

```
var something = true ? new object() : null;
```

**This does not compile:**

```
true ? new object() : null;
```

Comment: Well you *can* nest ternary statements (else-if), but anyone who does so deserve pain.

Comment: @Crono also ternarys require assignment which I just remembered, so I updated my answer.

Comment: Let's make that __Ternary statements are strictly for assignments__

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I see where you guys are getting at and I realize now that it would be "pain" in the end with what I was thinking.

Comment: @TehPirate if you got your answer, then all is well. :)